# Matrix of linear map on vector space whose elements are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space with a basis $B=\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, and let $F:V\to V$ be a linear map. The matrix of $F$ in the basis $B$ is given by

$$
[F]_B = ([F(e_1)]_B,\dots,[F(e_n)]_B)
$$

But if I consider for example the vector space $M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})$ of $m\times n$ matrices under matrix addition, in which the standard basis is given by $B = \{E_{ij} : 1\leq i \leq m, \ 1\leq j \leq n\}$, where $E_{ij}$ is the $m\times n$ matrix with zeros everywhere except in position $ij$ where it is $1$, then how would I go about writing out the matrix for a linear operator $F:M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})\to M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})$? Would it be

$$
[F]_B = ([F(E_{11})]_B,[F(E_{21})]_B,\dots,[F(E_{m1})]_B,[F(E_{12})]_B,[F(E_{22})]_B,\dots,[F(E_{mn})]_B),
$$

or

$$
[F]_B = ([F(E_{11})]_B,[F(E_{12})]_B,\dots,[F(E_{1n})]_B,[F(E_{21})]_B,[F(E_{22})]_B,\dots,[F(E_{mn})]_B),
$$

or is some other way preferable? I think it probably does not matter as long as one keeps track of which coordinate corresponds to which $E_{ij}$. But I am not sure, and I would like to know if there is some standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I think it probably does not matter as long as one keeps track of which coordinate corresponds to which $E_{ij}."$

Exactly. What is really important is the operator action on the basis elements, in your case the action of $F$ on the $E_{ij}$. The matrix representation for an operator in a given basis does depend on the basis *ordering*, a permutation in the basis ordering will correspond to a column permutation for the operator matrix representation and you only need to keep track of it.